# Oracle 12c Forms & Reports setup_fmw_12.2.1.3.0_fr_win64.exe installation error: self-extraction to C:\...... .tmp failed

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracleforms, oraclereports

While installing Oracle 12c Forms & Reports: setup_fmw_12.2.1.3.0_fr_win64.exe file, got installation error: self-extraction to C:...... .tmp failed

How can I successfully install the Oracle Forms Reports?
I already have installed the weblogic infrastructure.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is solved now. The solution is do not unzip setup_fmw_12.2.1.3.0_fr_win64-2.zip file and keep it together with the first exe file, setup_fmw_12.2.1.3.0_fr_win64.exe. Run the exe in admin mode.

Answer (score 1):

What does the log file say the reason was? First two reasons that come to mind are Disk Space or File Write Permissions.

Open this file in a text editor and let us know what it says:
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2017-11-30_05-11-55PM\launcher2017-11-30_05-11-55PM.log

Answer (score 1):

In Winddows 7 and 8 works fine if you change the version fmw_12.2.1.3.0_fr_win64 for setup_fmw_12.2.1.0.0_fr_win64

Unzip the file and run as administrator.

Note: 
You have to have jdk, but you can use jre-10.0.2_windows-x64_bin that already contains jdk-8u181-windows-x64.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this problem. It turned out the file I was opening had a modified name (I have downloaded it second time and it had a " (2)" at the end). When I renamed it and opened as administrator, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The zip file of Disk 2, should be placed in the same location of Disk 1 executable setup_fmw_12.2.1.3.0_fr_win64.exe, and run as admin. It worked for me in Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 files with one difference, zip folder had different last digit.
I made it's names same and add to zip file "-2".